# Boolean type - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I'm looking for some help with boolean. I searched around the internet and found out there's no real boolean type in Oracle, but came out with this :

```
create table tbool (bool char check (bool in (0,1));
insert into tbool values(0);
insert into tbool values(1);
```

I'm looking to add it to a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Member
(
    mem_id NUMBER(8) CONSTRAINT mem_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
        mem_registeration DATE,
        (Here I want the boolean, called IsEligble) 
);
```

I just don't know how to enter it. Any help? thanks in advance!

Comment: `... iseligble char ... CHECK (iseligble IN ('0', '1')) ...`? (Or maybe rather use `number(1)` that's less confusing with 0 and 1 -- `... iseligble number(1) ... CHECK (iseligble IN (0, 1)) ...`)

Comment: There is a Boolean type in Oracle, it just isn't available in SQL. https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2633

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Member
(
    mem_id NUMBER(8) CONSTRAINT mem_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    mem_registeration DATE,
    is_eligible number(1) default 0 not null,
    constraint ck_is_eligible check ( is_eligible in ( 0, 1 ))
);
```

(I think. Haven't tested it. Set your default as appropriate for your application.) You can also use 'Y' and 'N' for your pseudo-boolean values. I think it's just a matter of style.

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you very much!